# FPGA Connection to web

Tags: fpga

I know some FPGA board might have the Ethernet port. However, how could I connect an FPGA board to the internet to receive and decode TCP/UDP packets? Basically, I would like to receive some data from a server through TCP or UDP and process it on the board.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Add a softcore processor (e.g. Nios2 or Microblaze), an OS with a TCP/IP stack (eCos, Linux, uCosII, etc.) and maybe a web server.

You'll need an ethernet PHY, of course, but even the ethernet MAC can be soft IP.

If you want to avoid a software solution, you could also use some kind of TOE (TCP Offload Engine) and put the entire TCP/IP stack in hardware on the FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as long as the necessary hardware (=phy) is on board, its no problem. One solution would be to process them with a softcore. But you could also process them direct in hardware. But be carefull a full TCP stack is very hard to implement in hardware, udp is no problem. E.g. one project there is NetFPGA.